# How can I connect to a remote server?

Tags: flask, networking, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a flask app to a ubuntu server. When I'm in local network of place A, if I want to connect to ubuntu server of this place, I just simply type ssh username@192.168.1.IP

But when I'm in another network of place B. How can I connect to ubuntu server of place A? I can't connect to it by ssh username@192.168.1.IP command anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the public ip of the other network and you need to configure port forwarding on the router